Using pywin32 and flask to build a windows update scanner and i am having a problem where any function using COM objects blocks the next function
As the title states, i am trying to build a remote windows update scanner in python using pywin32 and flask. My intended functionality is for a listener to receive a post request to the /trigger endpoint and start the instruction. If i use a function that needs COM objects, in this case the Windows Update Agent API, any instruction after the function does not run.
The function in question:
def scan_for_updates():
    """
    Scans for available Windows updates using the Windows Update Agent API.
    """
    try:
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()

        # Create a session with the Windows Update Agent
        update_session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Microsoft.Update.Session")
        update_searcher = update_session.CreateUpdateSearcher()

        # Search for updates that are not installed
        search_result = update_searcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")

        if search_result.Updates.Count == 0:
            print("No updates available.")
            return []

        displayed_updates = []  # List to store non-driver updates
        print("Available Updates:\n")

        for update in search_result.Updates:
            # Skip updates in the "Drivers" category
            if any(category.Name == "Drivers" for category in update.Categories):
                continue

            # Extract update details
            title = update.Title
            description = getattr(update, "Description", "No description available")
            kb_numbers = ", ".join([f"{kb}" for kb in update.KBArticleIDs]) if update.KBArticleIDs else "N/A"
            file_size_mb = int(update.MaxDownloadSize) / (1024 * 1024) if hasattr(update, "MaxDownloadSize") else 0

            # Parse and format LastDeploymentChangeTime
            deployment_date = "N/A"
            if hasattr(update, "LastDeploymentChangeTime"):
                try:
                    deployment_date = datetime.fromisoformat(str(update.LastDeploymentChangeTime)).strftime("%d-%m-%y")
                except ValueError:
                    deployment_date = "Invalid Date"

            # Add the update details to the list
            displayed_updates.append({
                "Title": title,
                "Description": description,
                "KB Number(s)": kb_numbers,
                "File Size (MB)": file_size_mb,
                "Last Deployment Date": deployment_date
            })

            # Display the update details
            print(f"Title: {title}")
            print(f"Description: {description}")
            print(f"KB Number(s): {kb_numbers}")
            print(f"File Size: {file_size_mb:.2f} MB")
            print(f"Last Deployment Date: {deployment_date}")
            print("-" * 50)

        # Display the total number of non-driver updates
        print(f"\nTotal Updates Found (excluding Drivers): {len(displayed_updates)}")

        return displayed_updates

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while scanning for updates: {e}")
        return []

    finally:
        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

This function is supposed to provide data for another function which parses this data into a CSV file. The flask app does not move on to the CSV creation function after this function.
I tried to explicitly run the function in a separate thread, that didnt yield any differences.
Explicit logging did not help with showing the problem. If i combine my csv creation and update scanning into one function, i get my desired result but it still blocks any instruction happening outside the function which prevents me from sending a response to my server to move on to the next device in the scan list.

Okay for some reason removing CoUninitialize() allows the script to move on to the next instruction... I dont know whether this is going to cause any memory problems but i i will have to work with it for now
